# iOS UI Testing using Xamarin on Windows

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ui-testing

I'm currently a `Mac` user using Parallels to develop with `Xamarin` on Windows `Visual Studio`.

My `iOS Simulator` run fine and I have no problem with the development of an iOS App. Point is, everything was fine until I decided to run some UI Test on both my Android and iOS app.

`Xamarin UITest` tell me that iOS Test are not supported on Windows.

Is there any way I can make it work ? Should I switch back on `Xamarin Studio` only for `iOS UI Testing` ? Is there any other option for simple UI Testing on both iOS and Android on Windows ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Depending on budget, you could look at [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud) which will give you access to test on thousands of specific devices.

Tests can be developed using `Xamarin.UITest` in Visual Studio then executed in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience in this area (Xamarin UITesting both Android and iOS).

I have not found Xamarin UITest to be "cross-platform".  In my opinion, you end-up writing separate projects, separate test solutions: one for Android, another for iOS.

Since you already have a Mac and already have Xamarin Studio at your disposal, you may as well concentrate your iOS testing efforts there, and use Visual Studio for Android.